# Running pre-import customizations in Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I need to do some customization on created VM either before importing it or just before running it first time. For instance, I need to clear stale NAT port forwarding rules that tend to be left after the box with the same name, remove some disk controllers (reattach existing disks to IDE controller instead of SATA for compatiblity with older OS revisions that do not understand SATA, etc).

There are `pre-boot` and `pre-import` events in Vagrant code, but I wonder if there's any way of running some virtualbox/vagrant commands before booting created vm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for running VBoxManage commands, see the "VBoxManage Customizations" chapter [in the docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html). The commands are by default run on `pre-boot` phase, but you can also specify the phase as a first argument:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize "pre-boot", ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 2]
  end
end
```

But I think there problem is that you don't have an easy and reliable way to get the disk image path.

Comment: Actually finding disk is easy: http://dpaste.com/1587145/ . Finding disk UUID should be good enough, I tested that vboxmanage storage-related cmds accept storage UUIDs.

Comment: Ah, nice! Vagrant could probably even support some `:disk_uuid` magic.

Comment: @John, can you re-post whatever was previously on dpaste, possibly as a gist or something more persistent?  Running into an issue where OS UUIDs aren't matching what VBoxManage reports, so trying to reconcile the two.